# Xcode shows error on Mac that doesn't show in VSCode for Flutter project in Different PC

Tags: xcode, flutter

This is the error:

```
lib/openNews.dart:134:28: Error: The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the class 'ScaffoldState'.

 - 'ScaffoldState' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart' ('../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showSnackBar'.

      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(

                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I use my PC to run the exact same project file on VSCode, it runs on emulator just fine with no error messages, but if I run it in my mac, it makes this error.

Interestingly this wasn't an issue yesterday because it ran fine that day, but today is weird.

Comment: Can you check if you are using the same version of flutter on both systems?

Comment: seems to be mac is using higher flutetr version and that PC has older flutter version
as  the method use for snackbar was deprected in new version  : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showSnackBar.html